Can't load Gemma 2 9b on 2xT4 in Kaggle using the Accelerate and Trl
I am using the below script in using the accelerate but it never gets loaded on 2xT4 GPUs on Kaggle as while loading the first  GPU fills up and raises the memory error without reaching the second GPU. When I try to run this without accelerate (python train.py) it loads perfectly, however, there are still issues with forward pass and after loading still runs out of memory.
accelerate config:
compute_environment: LOCAL_MACHINE
deepspeed_config: {}
distributed_type: DEEPSPEED
fp16: False
machine_rank: 0
main_process_ip: 0
main_process_port: 0
main_training_function: main
mixed_precision: "no"
num_machines: 1
num_processes: 2
use_cpu: false

import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig
from peft import LoraConfig
from trl import SFTTrainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments

device_map="FSDP" # for FSDP and running with `accelerate launch test_sft.py`


dataset_name = 'taher30/python-docs-gemma'
dataset = load_dataset(dataset_name)
device_map = {'model.embed_tokens': 0,
 'lm_head': 0,
 'model.layers.0': 0,
 'model.layers.1': 0,
 'model.layers.2': 0,
 'model.layers.3': 0,
 'model.layers.4': 0,
 'model.layers.5': 0,
 'model.layers.6': 0,
 'model.layers.7': 0,
 'model.layers.8': 0,
 'model.layers.9': 0,
 'model.layers.10': 0,
 'model.layers.11': 0,
 'model.layers.12': 0,
 'model.layers.13': 0,
 'model.layers.14': 0,
 'model.layers.15': 0,
 'model.layers.16': 0,
 'model.layers.17': 0,
 'model.layers.18': 0,
 'model.layers.19': 1,
 'model.layers.20': 1,
 'model.layers.21': 1,
 'model.layers.22': 1,
 'model.layers.23': 1,
 'model.layers.24': 1,
 'model.layers.25': 1,
 'model.layers.26': 1,
 'model.layers.27': 1,
 'model.layers.28': 1,
 'model.layers.29': 1,
 'model.layers.30': 1,
 'model.layers.31': 1,
 'model.layers.32': 1,
 'model.layers.33': 1,
 'model.layers.34': 1,
 'model.layers.35': 1,
 'model.layers.36': 1,
 'model.layers.37': 1,
 'model.layers.38': 1,
 'model.layers.39': 1,
 'model.layers.40': 1,
 'model.layers.41': 1,
 'model.norm': 1}
model_name = 'google/gemma-2-9b-it'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
print("Loading Model.....")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code = True,
                                             use_cache = False, torch_dtype = torch.float16, device_map = "auto")
print("Model Loaded!!!")

model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

lora_alpha = 8
lora_dropout = 0.1
lora_r = 32
peft_config = LoraConfig(
    lora_alpha=lora_alpha,
    lora_dropout=lora_dropout,
    r=lora_r,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    target_modules=["k_proj", "q_proj", "v_proj", "up_proj", "down_proj", "gate_proj"],
    modules_to_save=["embed_tokens", "input_layernorm", "post_attention_layernorm", "norm"],
)

max_seq_length = 2048*2
output_dir = "./results"
per_device_train_batch_size = 1
gradient_accumulation_steps = 1
optim = "adamw_torch"
save_steps = 10
logging_steps = 1
learning_rate = 2e-4
max_grad_norm = 0.3
max_steps = 10
warmup_ratio = 0.1
lr_scheduler_type = "cosine"
training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
    optim=optim,
    save_steps=save_steps,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    bf16=False,
    max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
    max_steps=max_steps,
    warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
    group_by_length=True,
    lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    gradient_checkpointing_kwargs = {"use_reentrant": True},
    report_to="wandb",
)

gemma_format = """###System:
{}

###Model:
{}
"""
EOS_TOKEN = tokenizer.eos_token

def get_sentences(sample):
    # texts = []
    messages = sample['messages']
    # print(messages[0])
    if messages[0]['role']=='user':
        user_resp = messages[0]['content']
    if messages[1]['role'] == 'model':
        model_resp = messages[1]['content']
    text = gemma_format.format(user_resp, model_resp) + EOS_TOKEN
    # texts.append(text)
    return { "text" : text, }
# for i in dataset:
#     get_sentences(i)

dataset = load_dataset("taher30/python-docs-gemma", split = "train")
dataset = dataset.map(get_sentences)

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
)

# handle PEFT+FSDP case
trainer.model.print_trainable_parameters()
if getattr(trainer.accelerator.state, "fsdp_plugin", None):
    from peft.utils.other import fsdp_auto_wrap_policy

    fsdp_plugin = trainer.accelerator.state.fsdp_plugin
    fsdp_plugin.auto_wrap_policy = fsdp_auto_wrap_policy(trainer.model)

# Train
trainer.train()```

I tried getting using the device map as in the script but it didn't make any difference.
